# Customer Deleted; Get old Order History back

Tags: magento-1.9, customer

Customer deleted in Magento from Backend accidentally.

Created a new Customer in Magento Backend to recover Customer.

But how to add the old Order History?

```
UPDATE
sales_flat_order
SET customer_id = 12345
WHERE
customer_email = 'customer@example.org'
```

Old Order now has the new customer_id but Magento Backend does not show this Order in Order-History???

> Q: How to connect Orders to a Customer in SQL??

Comment: Can you please elaborate more which order history you are referring. Please share the screenshot of the admin panel. Regards,
Arpita

Comment: he deleted customer accidentally. now he has added new customer to recover data. and updated new customer id in order table but magento not showing order in backend

Comment: You can add the new customer ID to the specific orders in `sales_flat_order` and `sales_flat_order_grid`

Answer (score 0):

You have to update `sales_flat_order_grid` too:

```
UPDATE
sales_flat_order_grid
SET customer_id = 12345
WHERE
customer_email = 'customer@example.org'
```

Answer (score 0):

YES, issue is to Update `sales_flat_order_grid`, aswell.
But it has no column `customer_id`. 
Best to do it with `LEFT JOIN` in one call:

```
UPDATE
sales_flat_order sfo
LEFT JOIN 
sales_flat_order_grid sfog
ON
sfo.entity_id = sfog.entity_id
SET 
sfo.customer_id = 12345,
sfog.customer_id = 12345
WHERE
sfo.customer_email = 'customer@example.org'
```

After this entirely order history is attached to the customer back.

!! THX GUYS !! Saved me bad nights!!

Answer (score 0):

In case of multiple deletion, use below 2 query. note that run these SQL in same order as i have written here.

For `sales_flat_order` Table

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order as SFO 
INNER JOIN customer_entity as C 
ON C.email = SFO.customer_email 
SET SFO.customer_id = C.entity_id 
WHERE SFO.customer_is_guest = 0
```

AND FOR `sales_flat_order_grid` Table

```
UPDATE sales_flat_order_grid as SFOG 
INNER JOIN sales_flat_order as SFO 
ON SFO.entity_id = SFOG.entity_id 
SET SFOG.customer_id = SFO.customer_id
```